# FQDN on Local Network?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, centos-7, hostname

I am stuck with **OVirt 1.1 Setup** on Centos 7

Ovirt want a hostname that is fully qualified and throwing error on webpage **The client is not authorized to request an authorization. It's required to access the system using FQDN.**

```
#/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain.
```

I Put `localhost.localdomain.` in ovirt setup configuration

Here is My network Architecute

```
ISP -------------------> Modem (WAN IP)  --------------> Ovirt Machine
Carrier Grade Nat        10.0.2.243 / 192.168.1.1         192.168.1.3
```

I need to learn Ovirt Virtualization on local network.

My Question is, **Can i setup fqdn on local network** to make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

[According to this mailing list](http://lists.ovirt.org/pipermail/users/2013-June/014703.html), it looks as though you need the actual IP of the host, not 127.0.0.1. and to make the hostname the same as your engine e.g.

```
 192.168.1.3        server.name
```

*Please note that these are just examples and you will need to match these entries with your own real-world configuration.*

That said, according to the current [oVirt Quickstart Guide](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/quickstart/quickstart-guide/), the default FQDN is "server.name" if none is specified.

You may apparently also need to adjust your SELinux config under */etc/selinux/config* with

```
selinux=permissive.
```

If you do change the SELinux config, you'll need to reboot for the new config to actually take effect.

There are also apparently [general instructions on changing the engine host name](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/networking/changing-engine-hostname/) as well as an [engine rename tool](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/admin-guide/chap-Utilities/) (used in the final step of the previous link).

Comment: My Gateway is 192.168.1.1 and Ovirt machine is 192.168.1.3, so how come 192.168.0.50 ? 
I'll appreciate if you elaborate

Comment: Apologies. Those were just examples. I replaced the IP with your host (as specified), though you still need to match up the hostname entry with whatever your configuration is.

Comment: I tried with ovirt.domain.local but not luck yet, here what i am getting again and again http://imgur.com/a/JpSWh

Comment: Try using "server.name" as the FQDN in your hosts file (this is the default setting according to the current quickstart guide). Otherwise, you may need to take steps to change the FQDN in oVirt if you don't remember what you entered for that step.

Comment: I settled up "server.name" in hosts and changed ovirt fqdn using "I am changing ovrit fqdn via this "/usr/share/ovirt-engine/setup/bin/ovirt-engine-rename" to "server.name", SELINUX Disabled, Rebooted and still same error.